# How to convert negative field values to positive?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have an xyz file that I want to convert negative field values in the z column to positive values. How do I do this with field calculator?

Comment: Thanks that does indeed change the values to positive but what  I didn't make clear was that I want to keep them as the original values but without the minus symbol (effectively multiplying all negative values by -1)

Answer (score 8):

In QGIS you can use `abs("fieldname")` to turn them into always positive values.

Comment: And -abs("fieldname") to go from positive to negative which just helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS desktop you could use the following python script in the field calculator, where you would create a new field (say, FIELDNAME2) and calculate the following (where FIELDNAME1 is your original values):

Pre-Logic script

```
def values(n):
    if n < 0:
        return n * -1
    else:
        return n
```

bottom window

```
values(!FIELDNAME1!)
```